# SWIFT TableView not loading text

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, swift

I am making a tableView programatically. For some reason the table view is always empty. Please help me find the bug. Here is my code

// Set all view we will need

```
func setupTableView() {
    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, self.heighTableView))
    self.tableView!.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, CGFloat(self.heighTableViewHeader)))
    self.tableView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

self.tapMapViewGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapMapView:")
        self.tapTableViewGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapTableView:")
        self.tapTableViewGesture!.delegate = self
        self.tableView!.tableHeaderView?.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapMapViewGesture!)
        self.tableView!.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapTableViewGesture!)

        // Init selt as default tableview's delegate & datasource
        //self.tableView!.dataSource = self
        self.tableView!.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView!)
    }


// UITableViewDataSource Methods
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->CGFloat {

    return 80

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var identifier = "Cell"

       var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as UITableViewCell?

        cell!.textLabel!.text = "Hello World !"
   // }
 return cell!
}
```

Comment: You need to setup a delegate and datasource for this table. And is there no "numberOfRowsInSection" ?

Comment: I did that. But still not working. I have been stuck on this for over a week :( Here is the swift class: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ye0a5vf8s66wnn8/MapSuperClass.swift?dl=0

Comment: Your cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called.

Comment: I have updated the post. Still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
```

then replace your function by copying this two functions by command + click on `UITableViewDataSource`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

}
```

and other one is :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

}
```

and put all the code into this two function and try again becouse in your code this two functions are not getting called but by doing this your function will called and you have put all the required code into this function.

and also remove comment from

`self.tableView!.dataSource = self`

May be this can help you.

**Edit For this Answer:**

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    var identifier : NSString = "Cell"

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? UITableViewCell

    if !(cell != nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "Hello World"
    return cell!
    }
```

Comment: still didnt work. I removed the function setupTableView and put all the code in viewDidLoad. Still no luck.

Comment: now the app is crashing: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The cell is not loading for some reason. Pls check dropbox link

Comment: Yeah I see that I think your cell become nil at runtime

Comment: trying adding an IBOutlet

Comment: I am doing it programatically.

Comment: your code in cellForRowAtIndexPath have some problem because when I create IBOutlet In other project I am getting same runtime error.

Comment: can you give me a sample code that works on Swift GM ?

Comment: i think the problem is in the code where you setup the tableView. Its not the code for the cell.

Comment: I have updated the answer now you might understand..:)